# Import CSV with longitude and latitude coordinates in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, csv, vector-layer

I have a CSV file with the first two columns containing longitude and latitude values.
Now I want to create a point layer via the "add delimited text-layer" in QGIS. I have a problem with my OSM standard map. Which coordinate refrence system do I need?

[image]

Comment: Decimal degrees are EPSG 4326.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clear the Z-field and, as Erik said, set the CRS to EPSG:4326 - WGS 84.

[image: Geometry Definition setup]